# WooCommerce shop, my account, cart every page redirect to home page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, redirect

Here is my website: [smitafashions.com](http://smitafashions.com)

Whenever I click on any page from the menu or the products in the home page, 
every link redirects me back to the home page

I tried clearing cache
Save permalinks 
Delete .htacccess
Disable sg optimizer plugin

I had created a single product page using Elementor Pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that Go to Settings --> Permalinks --> I have used custom permalinks
So change it to another default permalink and save

Solves the problem